# Fancybox iframe groups (gallery)

Tags: fancybox

I am wondering if it is possible to use fancybox to group php pages like it groups images (with the left and right arrows in the popup).
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes

```
<a rel="test" href="http://jquery.com/">Iframe (75% width and height)</a><br/>
<a rel="test" href="http://jqueryui.com">google</a>




 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel=test]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
});
    </script>
```

I have created this test page http://jsfiddle.net/Flatlineato/Kne3n/1/